# Run a webbrowser and continue script without close the browser

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I need help with this code:

```
import webbrowser

chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open('https://www.google.com/')
print('test browser')
```

it open chrome and visit the website, but don't print until I close the browser.

If I use this one:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/')
print('test browser')
```

It run default browser(brave), visit the website and print correctly.

How can I run X browser and print without need of close it to continue script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new Thread and in that thread open the browser:

```
from threading import Timer

def open_browser():
    webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/')

Timer(1, open_browser).start()
print(“test”)
```

Everything that has to do with interaction of the browser should now be placed in `def open_browser():`

This code will set a timer for 1 millisecond and then execute the function within a seperate thread, so your code keeps executing.

Comment: There is the same problem using it with or without def, but at least it can run a separate thread to continue the script